# Write data from vector to file. C++

Tags: c++

I have Shapes class and gShapes vector.
I'm writing objects form vector to file like this.

```
char* str;
vector<Shape*>::iterator it;
for( it = gShapes.begin(); it != gShapes.end(); it++ )
{       
    str = reinterpret_cast<char*>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(*it));
    saveFile.write(str, sz);
}
```

It was working perfect until I add dynamic memory in my class and now this code writes pointer in file not data.

Comment: You need to fully serialize your object.  For example:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always [except in EXTREMELY rare situations, just to satisfy the pedants that will point out those extremely rare situations exist], when storing data to a file, the data needs to be "serialized" - in other words, stored in a "flat" format - not pointers, references, or other indirect forms.

So, if you have a pointer in your `Shape`, then you need to "unravel" that pointer, just as if you were printing the content using a `operator <<` for your object.

Comment: Oh I dunno, you could write out pointers, whole structures, etc in some rare situations (like only writing and reading what you wrote in the same run of the application)

Comment: Better now? I must admit that aside from the odd mistake, I don't think I've written a pointer to a file in the 30 or so years I've been writing code more or less for a living and as a hobby.

Comment: Yes, I have (rarely) done that. But I still think we're being pedantic and it's unlikely that the original poster is looking to store offsets to other objects in the file based on pointers within the data structure being stored.